# android, delete multiple rows in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row

I need to delete multiple rows from my database table. 
This is my  code for deletion

```
String[] paragraph;
.....
//here you can to put various strings within it (1 or more)
.....
db.delete(mytablename,"Paragraph = ?",paragraphs);
```

It works with 1 string, but it doesn't work with more strings.
Can someone help me, please?

Here there is the error shown by LogCat:

```
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x377500
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_bind_string(Native Method)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:241)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.bindObjectToProgram(DatabaseUtils.java:191)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1769)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at it.tirocinio.Segnalibro$3$3.onClick(Segnalibro.java:196)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-11 11:03:01.400: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you need an equal number of ?:s as you have entries in your `paragraph` array, e.g. "Paragraph=? OR Paragraph=? OR Paragraph=?" for an array with a length of 3.

Comment: It wont work for more than one string. `Paragraph = ?` in db.delete will accept only one selection argument.
you can use something like `db.rawquery(DELETE FROM table WHERE columnName IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')); `

Comment: I understand the reason, I can't use the your solutions because the number of strings is variable. I think that I  must use a for and repeat the delete statement. Any advice?  I would like to have the best solution.

Comment: @sleone08 I dont think `for` loop for is a good approach because that would be too costly to have one query each for deletion of a row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use this way:


for(int i = 0 ; i < paragraphs.lenght;i++)
{

db.delete(mytablename,"Paragraph ='"+paragraphs[i]+"'",null);
}
```

Comment: perfect solution.. :)

Comment: Isn't there a way to do so in a single query? this approach would be too costly for (say) some 100 rows.